# Did ComponentScan work in my SpringMVCproject?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss

I have a project based on SpringMVC 5 and an error happened when I tried to run it on JBoss EAP 7.3.

> 14:33:14,134 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Creating shared instance of
> singleton bean 'userDetailsService'
>
> 14:33:14,140 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Context initialization failed:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed;......nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.aaa.bbb.security.service.UserService'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Here's the code of class "UserDetailsServiceImpl":

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired 
    private SessionUtils sessionUtils;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userID) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.get(userID);
        
        if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
        sessionUtils.expireUserSessions(user.getUser_name());   // Force expire other session
        
        return new UserDetailsInfo(user);
    }
}
```

And here's the code of class "UserService":

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User get(String id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public User getuUserByUsername(String user_name) {
        return userRepository.getuUserByUsername(user_name);
    }

    public int incLoginErrorCount(String id) {
        return userRepository.incLoginErrorCount(id);
    }

    public int resetLoginErrorCount(String id) {
        return userRepository.resetLoginErrorCount(id);
    }

    public int lockCount(String id) {
        return userRepository.lockCount(id);
    }
    
    public int changeUPassword(String id, String password) {
        return userRepository.changeUPassword(id, password);
    }
}
```

And I'm using "WebAppInitializer":

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private String TMP_FOLDER = "/tmp";
    private int MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), new MultipartFilter(),
                new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter() };
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        super.registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());

    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {

        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(TMP_FOLDER, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE,
                MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE * 2, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE / 2);
        registration.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);

    }
}
```

To call "WebMvcConfig":

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.aaa.bbb"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
      DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**", "/resources/**", "/resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/log/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/", "classpath:/js/", "classpath:/json/", "/webjars/", "/META-INF/");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {

        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasenames("message/messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return source;
    }
}
```

If @ComponentScan worked, this error should not happen.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use @Service annotation on the UserDetailsServiceImpl class too. Since it is not annotated, componentScan doesn't know that it should autowire the services inside it. So UserDetailsServiceImpl class should look like this.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired 
private SessionUtils sessionUtils;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userID) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.get(userID);
    
    if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
    sessionUtils.expireUserSessions(user.getUser_name());   // Force expire other session
    
    return new UserDetailsInfo(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.@atakansaltik
I've found the reason is another Dispatcher existed in the lib classes that referring by my project, it's duplicate, so that the Dispatcher in my project couldn't be started, therefore the necessary bean wasn't loaded.